# Is there anyway we can use Spring Cloud Functions + AWS Lambda adapter to process http file uploads?

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload, aws-lambda, spring-cloud

I am new to AWS and FAAS.  My work place is interested in processing HTTP file upload with AWS Lambda and Spring Boot.  A quick research led me to Spring Cloud Functions + AWS Lambda adapter; however, documentation doesn't cover anything related to HTTP file uploads, so I wonder if it is possible to do that with Spring Cloud Function or I have to fallback to AWS Lambda Spring Boot integration (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container)?

Thanks in advance for your kind enlightenment!

Answer (score 1):

AWS lambda can be triggered in many ways like API gateway, S3Event, SNS notification and SQS. API gateway integrates lambda with HTTP end points. API gateway is not designed to handle file uploads. API gateway converts binary data to base64 encoded text. Handling binary data as text consumes a lot of memory and processing gets tricky as well.

Also API gateway has a 10MB limit on payload size. The best approach to upload files is using S3. Even better approach would be to use a lambda function to generate a pre-signed S3 url to upload files.

Spring cloud function when integrated with an API gateway is intended to expose a single HTTP endpoint. However AWS Lambda spring boot integration by awslabs can expose multiple end points. Choose the approach that best works you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Glad that helped.